# Parse PHP Soap call

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, soap, wsdl

I have read multiple posts on this topic, but none have been specific enough to my case to solve the issue.

Basically I am making a soap call to a wsdl service which returns an array of information.  What I need to do is parse that information into a couple variables.

Here's the code where I instantiate the soap client then make the call to the wsdl service passing in an SSN.  Now the $result contains all the information that the service passes back.  I can do a var_dump($result); to see all the returned values meaning my problem isn't with the soap client or call.

```
$client = new nusoap_client($url, array('soap_version' =>    SOAP_1_1, 'response_timeout' => 10 ));

$result = $client->call('getWSDL_element', array('SSN' => $SSN));
```

However I need to know how to get the results into variables using a loop.  I've tried the following without success:

```
        foreach ($result["fullName"] as $fullName){
        $first = $fullName["firstName"];
        $last = $fullName["lastName"];
    }
```

Now what I expect is for the $first and $last variables to contain the first and last names provided by the wsdl service.  However my syntax must be wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a `var_dump` of `$result` I can't be certain but I'd guess this is what you're looking for:

```
$first = $result['fullName']['firstName'];
$last = $result['fullName']['lastName'];
```

Comment: Thanks that gives me the correct syntax, and from there I was able to extract the results out of the wsdl response that I needed!